# Selenium and ckEditor

Tags: testing, selenium, ckeditor

Does anybody know How I can get the ckEdtior to work with Selenium.
I'm not able to get the focus to the "html edit" field or change the value of the html field.

Does anybody has experience with this ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just for completing the anwser:
I got it to work with:
`runScript("CKEDITOR.instances['InstanceName'].setData('<p>testContent</p>');")`
It did not work with the getEval command.

Comment: In my Angular project, CKEDITOR is undefined, but the steps in this link worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47339951/unable-to-type-in-ckeditor-with-selenium-chrome-62

Answer (score 1):

When I have had a to test against WYSIWYG editors I have had to build my own mechanism to work in the content area. Normally it involves having to set the inner HTML of object and then start using the page manipulators in the tool bars.

With Selenium 2 you will be able to send keystrokes in so that they work better and a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

Working in Selenium:

```
selenium.runScript("for(var i in CKEDITOR.instances) { var x = CKEDITOR.instances[i]; " + " x.setData('" + texto + "'); }");
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could wrap your code in `` so that it gets formatted correctly. Also explaining a bit about your solution goes along way of earning that rep!

Comment: Little improvement for Selenium IDE, this adds unique string to each ckeditor instance but first waits until all instances are loaded. http://pastebin.com/cMqbsvgR

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution that worked for me. You can insert a user-extension.js (Options > options > Selenium Core Extension > Browse ) writing the following:

```
 Selenium.prototype.doInsertCKEditor = function(locator,word) 
{ 
    this.doWaitForCondition("var x = Selenium.browserbot.findElementOrNull('//td[@id=\"cke_contents_form \"]');x != null;", "50000"); 
    this.doRunScript("CKEDITOR.instances['"+locator+"'].setData('"+word 
+"');"); 
}
```

This will add the insertCKEditor option in the Command options of Selenium IDE.