# Need to automate the Primefaces Editor component in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: primefaces, editor, webdriver

I have a Primefaces 3.5 component called "Editor" inside a dialog in my applicaiton. I use selenium webdriver to automate AUT. I am unable to automate it as it does not have any id's and when I identified this in Firebug, the xpath is displayed as just an HTML file and I am unable to enter text inside this HTML file and do any basic operations.

Is it possible to automate this component?

Comment: Primefaces seems to be using [CLEditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/) under the hood for the editor component. Also see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9957655/332248). Here is a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2613493/332248) about how to access the CLEditor from webdriver (using javascript).

Answer (score 0):

I have answered two similar questions before. Since Primefaces 3.5 uses CLEditor, so the second link below provide a detailed answer. Please feel free to have a look.

- [Interact with a cute editor using webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16114854/1177636)
- [Using C# with selenium and cleditor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17054430/1177636).

Basically, you locate the `iframe` first, then use `JavascriptExecutor` or `SendKeys` to `<body>`