# Unable to type in CKEditor with Selenium + Chrome 62

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, ckeditor, selenium-chromedriver

In one of my Selenium test cases, I need to type something into a CKEditor text area.
It **works fine with Chromedriver 2.20 + Chrome 59**. But since I upgraded to Chrome 62, the textarea isn't detected anymore. Selenium doesn't throw any exception, it just doesn't type in the CKEditor and goes on with the next step.

Method:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("some-cute-custom-angular-selector"));
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).click().perform();
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).sendKeys(element,notes).perform();
```

Any idea (other than downgrading)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it work for you, how about to try "hackish" approach to click by coordinates of CKEditor text area ?

Comment: The area is actually "clicked" (we can see it slightly changes color) but the text isn't sent...

Comment: One more suggestion, how about to remove from second Actions moveToElement or just chain all in one ? like this  `new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).click().sendKeys(notes).perform();`

Comment: Your solution actually works in my Angular project, with the css-selector being `"#myEditor .ck-content"`. For Chrome/driver 83.